# How to set LinearLayout HORIZONTAL using C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, orientation, xamarin

Im trying to align controls in my Android App.

I need to do this but using CODE / C# / Xamarin
This:  android:orientation="horizontaly"

This following code doesnt work in Xamarin (i guess good in java??):
.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

The accepted Method is : .Orientation
My code with missing/wrong code: see *** below

```
LinearLayout LLMain = new LinearLayout(this);
LLMain.Id = _intID;       
LLMain.AddView(textView(_intID));
LLMain.AddView(editText(_intID));
LLMain.Orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL; ***
linearlayoutList.Add(LLMain);
return LLMain;
```

How do I set this value: ??? LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL; ????

Thank you 
Martin

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
LLMain.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```